# Roots of $(x+a)^n+x^n+(x-a)^n=0$ are either real or purely imaginary?

Tags: number-theory, complex-numbers

> **Question:** For any $a\in \Bbb R$ and $n\in\Bbb N^+$, prove all the roots of $$(x+a)^n+x^n+(x-a)^n=0$$ are either real or purely imaginary.

*Some thoughts so far:*

If $z$ is a root of the equation, it is easy to verify that $-z,\overline z, -\overline z$ are the roots, too. I tried to put $z=u+vi$ and $\overline z=u-vi$ into the equaion but it looks more complicated.

Any ideas to proceed?

Comment: Actually I don't know whether this is true or not. I "proved" the cases $n\le 7$ by Wolframalpha.

Comment: Some insufficient thoughts: (1) it's enough to consider the case $a=1$ by scaling, and (2) when we expand out, we are left with only even or only odd powers of $x$, so it's enough to show that after substituting $x^2 = y$ and possibly dividing by $x$, the resulting polynomial $P(y)$ has only real roots.

Comment: @MishaLavrov: Yes, and it seems hard to prove "all zeros of $P(y)$ are real" for big $n$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your conjecture is true. In fact, we will prove the following:

**Theorem:** Let $P_{n,a}(x)$ be the polynomial
$$P_{n,a}(x) = (x-a)^n + x^n + (x+a)^n,$$
where $n\in \mathbb{N^+}$ and $0\neq a\in \mathbb{R}$. Then all roots of $P_{n,a}$ lie on the imaginary axis.

**Proof:** We make a few simplifications first. First note that the theorem holds for $P_{n,a}$ if and only it holds for $P_{n,1}$ since
$$(x-a)^n + x^n + (x+a)^n = 0 \iff \left(\frac{x}{a} - 1\right)^n + \left(\frac{x}{a}\right)^n + \left(\frac{x}{a} + 1\right)^n = 0,$$
so we will work with $P_n \equiv P_{n,1}$ without loss of generality from now on.

Now, note that $x=0$ is a root if and only if $n$ is odd. Because of this, it will also make things slightly more convenient for us to assume that $n$ is even. We can also do this without loss of generality because of the [Gauss-Lucas Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%E2%80%93Lucas_theorem) and the fact that $P'_n(x) = nP_{n-1}(x)$. So it suffices to work with $P_{2n}$.

Finally, with even exponent it suffices to consider the equivalent equation
$$x^{2n}\left(1-\frac{1}{x}\right)^{2n} + x^{2n} + x^{2n}\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)^{2n} = 0 \iff (1-iy)^{2n} + 1 + (1+iy)^{2n} = 0,\tag{*}$$
where we write $iy = x^{-1}$.

Let $z = 1+iy$. The solutions to $(*)$ with $y$ purely real (or equivalently, $x$ purely imaginary) corresponds to solutions of the equation
$$\mathrm{Re}(z^{2n}) = -\frac{1}{2}.\tag{**}$$
Now, assume $y$ is real. We will show that $(**)$ has $2n$ solutions, and hence that $P_{2n}(x) = 0$ has $2n$ imaginary roots.

Let us write $z = re^{i\theta}$ where $r=\sqrt{1+y^2}$ and $\tan \theta = y$. Then
$$z^{2n} = (1+y^2)^ne^{2ni\theta},$$
or equivalently
$$\mathrm{Re}(z^{2n}) = (1+\tan^2 \theta)^n\cos(2n\theta) = \frac{\cos(2n\theta)}{\cos^{2n}(\theta)}.$$
We can write $\cos(2n\theta)$ in terms of the [Chebyshev polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_polynomials) and hence we are looking for solutions of
$$T_{2n}(\cos\theta) + \frac{1}{2}\cos^{2n}\theta = 0,$$
therefore we will be finished if we can show that
$$T_{2n}(x) + \frac{1}{2}x^{2n} = 0 \tag{***}$$
has $n$ distinct solutions in the interval $(0,1)$, which will correspond to $2n$ distinct values of $\theta \in (-\pi/2 , \pi/2)$ which parametrizes the solutions of $(**)$.

Now, one of the defining features of Chebyshev polynomials is that all of their roots lie within the interval $(-1,1)$ and are symmetric about $0$. Hence $T_{2n}$ has precisely $n$ distinct positive real roots in $(0,1)$. Moreover, the magnitudes of the local maxima/minima of $T_n$ within the interval $(-1,1)$ are precisely $\pm 1$.

The addition of $\frac{1}{2}x^{2n}$ corresponds to a perturbation to $T_{2n}$ of magnitude less than $1$ on $(0,1)$ and hence cannot change the signs of any of local maxima/minima. Therefore by the intermediate value theorem, the addition of $\frac{1}{2}x^{2n}$ cannot change the fact that there exists $n$ distinct roots in $(0,1)$. This proves the result. $\square$

Comment: Very good use of Gauss-Lucas Theorem and the properties of Chebyshev polynomials! But why could we assume $y$ is real at the beginning, which is the "fact" that we need to prove? Isn't this argument circular?

Comment: It is necessary to consider the case $y\in\Bbb C$ with $\text{Im}(y)\ne 0$, too:)

Comment: @Tianlalu I show that there are $2n$ real solutions for $y$, which corresponds to $2n$ imaginary solutions for $P_{2n}$.  Since our polynomial is of degree $2n$, that must be all of them. There's no circularity and no need to consider other solutions.